# Office365/Sharepoint:: API Error when getting ParentUniqueId for a list item

Tags: rest, sharepoint, ms-office, office365, onedrive

I'm trying to identify the Parent Id for a list item.

I'm making the following call;

- https://{sitecollection}/{personal_site}/_api/Web/Lists(guid'blabla')/Items(blabla)?$select=ParentUniqueId

But it is giving me the following error;

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "The field or property 'ParentUniqueId' does not exist."
        }
    }
}
```

The same issue is with "ParentLeafName" and some others.

However, when I get the **/fields** (meta of  [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600182(v=office.15).aspx)  for a list) for this list, it mentions this field along with others, which means I'm doing the right call as I'm successfully getting other fields like

- https://{sitecollection}/{personal_site}/_api/Web/Lists(guid'blabla')/Items(blabla)?$select=ServerUrl

Result

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
        "id": "blabla",
        "uri": "blabla",
        "etag": "\"10\"",
        "type": "SP.Data.DocumentsItem"
    },
    "ServerUrl": "/personal/{site}/{filepath}"
   }
}
```

One thing I have noticed though, that these fields are case sensitive, that is, if i write "serverurl" it gives me the same error. Is this a case issue with "ParentUniqueId" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [ListItem resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433(v=office.15).aspx#bk_ListItem) in SharePoint 2013 REST interface does **not** expose `ParentUniqueId` property.

But you could use the following query to return `ParentUniqueId` property for `ListItem`:

`/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)/FieldValuesAsText?$select=ParentUniqueId`

### References

[Lists and list items REST API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, when I apply a filter against this unique Id, it gives me an empty list. Say I get the ParentUniqueId, I then make a call to {sitecollection}/{site}/items?$filter=UniqueId%20eq%20'theParentUniqueId' ... to get the parent item. I get an empty array. Even though I matched this Id with the unique Id of item itself. One thing I noticed is that ParenteUniqueId was in Caps so I tried the lower case too (to exactly match the two) but it still gives me an empty list.

Comment: Correction, the call I'm making is >>> https://{sitecollection}/{site}/_api/web/lists(guid'id')/items?$filter=UniqueId%20eq%20'ParentUniqueIdValue'

Comment: I also tried this >>> POST call >>> URL >>>  https://{sitecollection}/{site}/_api/web/lists(guid'id')/getitems >>> POST DATA >>> { 'query' : {'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, "ViewXml": "<View><Query><Where>
  <In>
    <FieldRef Name='UniqueId' />
    <Values>
      <Value Type='Lookup'>ParentUniqueIdValue</Value>
    </Values>
  </In>
</Where></Query></View>" } } >>> But the result is the same, empty array!

Comment: {
    "d": {
        "results": []
    }
}